# Magento 2: Get all shopping cart items, subtotal, grand total, billing & shipping address

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I want to  Get all shopping cart items, subtotal, grand total, billing & shipping address in one step checkout  Magento 2 in storefront (Home Page) .
according to the this link :

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html#add-your-step-to-the-checkout-page-layout

I added new step in checkout page according to this link :

> http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-all-shopping-cart-items-subtotal-grand-total-billing-shipping-address/

In part of (Using Dependency Injection (DI)) , on that site I do not know where is the directory of **`.phtml`** file and also **`.php`** file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this things.

1. Create one custom module into magento2.
2. Your block file something like this location.

   ```
   app\code\Vendor\Extension\Block\YourModule
   ```
3. Your `.phtml` file something like this location.

   ```
       app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\templates\
   ```